# replace the links from the html loaded using readfile

Tags: php, str-replace, readfile

I have been asked to show a website that I can not access his FTP after entering to domain that referees to my hosting. I decided to, using PHP, "copy" the html of the website I can not access using `readfile()`. It works great. Now when you enter to my website, you see the other website! But there is a problem. If you'll click on one of the buttons on the menu, you'll enter to the website using his domain, and not mine. Here is what I tried:

```
<base href="http://lantana.sitepro.co.il/">
<?php

    $contact = readfile("http://lantana.sitepro.co.il");
    echo $contact;

?>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("body").html().replace("http://lantana.sitepro.co.il","http://lantana.web-gen.net");
</script>
```

And I tried:

```
<base href="http://lantana.sitepro.co.il/">
<?php

    $find = "href=\"http://lantana.sitepro.co.il/";
    $replace = "href=\"http://lantana.web-gen.net/";
    $contact = readfile("http://lantana.sitepro.co.il/");
    echo str_replace($find, $replace, $contact);

?>
```

Both of them doesn't work. How can I do that whenever you click on the menu you'll enter using my domain, for example if in the original website the href on the `a` tag is `http://lantana.witepro.co.il/hello.php`, if you enter the website using the domain that shows the codes above, the href in the `a` tag will be `http://lantana.web-gen.net/hello.php`?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Javaskript for doing this**

```
var linkRewriter = function(a, b) {
    $('a[href*="' + a + '"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(a, b));
    });
};

linkRewriter('originalDomain.com', 'rewrittenDomain.com');
```

Found at: [change domain portion of links with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449480/change-domain-portion-of-links-with-javascript-or-jquery)

**or With PHP**

Something like

```
$contactfixed = str_replace("http://lantana.witepro.co.il","http://lantana.web-gen.net/","$contact");
```

Comment: But what about Google?  Is it OK? Thanks by the way.

Comment: when you replace the links onDocumentReady it might even work for google, probably it whould be better to do it with php if it must be google save

Comment: This code isn't working, probebly because I can add him only outside the `<html>` tags. Well, if you say PHP is better for google (and I guess it is the only way), so can you advice me how to do it?

Comment: You know that you have to call the linkRewrite with jquery after the page has been loaded or something before it will do something ?

Comment: with php use str_replace, maybe you have to tweek my updated answer to your needs