# Can the domain names be changed in hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Like a link is coming dynamically in a `<code><div></code>`, Can I change domain name of all the hyperlinks.

For example:-

This is hyperlink link tag

`<a href="http://onedomain.com/offers/testing-something/">`.

Can I change this to

```
<a href="http://seconddomain.com/offers/testing-something/">
```

dynamically with jquery. All other parameters in link should be same but on domain name should be changed. If it is possible then please explain how, I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Yes you can do that and it is possible.

Comment: look at jQuery's .attr('href')

Comment: Hi please see the updated question i just now updated the question

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488713/how-to-get-the-domain-name-from-anchor-href-attribute or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449480/change-domain-portion-of-links-with-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Use `replace()`:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('onedomain.com', 'seconddomain.com');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://onedomain.com/offers/testing-something/">link</a>
```

***@satpal solution will also work:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').attr('href', function(_, value) {
    return value.replace('onedomain.com', 'seconddomain.com');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://onedomain.com/offers/testing-something/">link</a>
```

Comment: You can aslo suggest `$('a').attr('href', function(_, value){
        return value.replace('onedomain.com', 'seconddomain.com');
    });`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the `host` property of the `<a>` elements using [`prop( propertyName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function)

```js
$('a').prop('host',function(){
  return 'seconddomain.com';
})

// for demo loop over elements and log adjusted href
.each(function(){
  console.log(this.href)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://onedomain.com/offers/testing-something/">
<a href="http://onedomain.com/offers/something-else/">
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href').replace("OLD-DOMAIN","NEW-DOMAIN");
});
```

Comment: The parameters after domain name should remain same after changing

Comment: I did'nt downvote but i got upper answer first that's why i upvote that first