# How to Change the Destination Domain Without Changing the Path in the Href of Anchor Tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about JavaScript.

How to change the **href** attribute value of an `<a/>` tag through JavaScript without changing the URL destination path

Example:

```
<a href="http://domain1.com/page">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://domain1.com/page2">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://domain1.com/page3">Link 3</a>
```

And I want to turn it into:

```
<a href="http://domain2.net/page">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://domain2.net/page2">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://domain2.net/page3">Link 3</a>
```

Thank you

Comment: If it counts for the whole document you could consider using [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change domain portion of links with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449480/change-domain-portion-of-links-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @Lain — The base element is easy to overlook and makes maintenance a pain so is best avoided in general. It won't help here anyway, it only affects relative URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `URL` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and seek out a polyfill for it if you need to support IE.

```js
const a = document.querySelector("a");
const original_href = a.href;
const url = new URL(original_href);
url.host = "domain2.com";
const new_href = "" + url;
a.href = new_href;
console.log(new_href);
```

```html
<a href="http://domain1.com/page">Link 1</a>
```